# Homogeneous ideals

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals, graded-rings

> Let $I\subseteq T$ be a homogeneous ideal. If $I_i=T_i$ for some $i$ then $I_j=T_j,\ \forall j\geq i$.

It is easy to see that it is true for some examples. Does anybody have any ideas for proving it in general cases?

For example, $T=k[x,y]$ and $I=(x,y)$. So we have $T_i=I_i$ for every $i$

Comment: Can you clarify the notation?

Comment: $I_i=T_i\iff T_i\subseteq I$, that is, $I$ contains all monomials of degree $i$. Then, since $I$ is an ideal, and $T_{i+1}=T_1T_i$ we get $T_{i+1}\subseteq I$, and so on. (This works for any strongly graded ring $T$.)

Comment: If $T$ is an arbitrary graded ring the claim can fail.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean $T=k[x_0,\ldots,x_n]$, and $I$ is a homogeneous ideal, and $T_i$ means the degree $i$ part of $T$, namely $T_i=(\mathfrak m)_i$, where $\mathfrak m$ is the ideal $(x_0,\ldots,x_n)$.

Then here's a hint.

Note that $\mathfrak m \cdot \mathfrak m^i = \mathfrak m^{i+1}$.

Thus if $I_i=T_i$ for some $I$, meaning $I_i= \mathfrak m^i/\mathfrak m^{i+1}$ as vector spaces, we get
$$
I_{i+1} \supset (\mathfrak m I_i)_{i+1} = (\mathfrak m \cdot \mathfrak m^i)_{i+1} = (\mathfrak m^{i+1})_{i+1}.
$$

Comment: your proof is okay. the only things must be done is some edits.

Comment: I_{i+1} \supseteq \mathfrak m I_i = \mathfrak m \cdot \mathfrak m^i= \mathfrak m^{i+1}=T_{i+1} $$. And as we know $I_{i}\subseteq T_{i}$ for every $ i$. So we have done. Actually, I wanted to prove it by contradiction. Suppose that there exits an element like $a_{i+1}\in I_{i+1}$ such that $ a_{i+1}\not\in T_{i+1}$. So $a_{i+1}\not\in I_{i+1}\cap T_{i+1}$. Have any Ideal for keeping?